# Count number of lines of code over time in sourcegraph?

Tags: sourcegraph

I want to build nice insights graph depicting how the lines count in a file changed over time.

Comment: Looking into this for you.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished using the following query:

`file:^path/to/file.ext$ \n \n patterntype:regexp`

[image]

Shoutout to the Code Insights team for their help on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jdorfman!  But still preview shows me a straight line  should the time scale change that?

Comment: @Stranger95 you are welcome! Try adjusting the granularity, e.g. https://share.getcloudapp.com/OAu2LOAL

Comment: @Stranger95 I updated the query. Add another `/n`

Comment: @Stranger95 this is a hack that works _sometimes_.

Comment: I found that the line counts were slightly inaccurate, but removing a `\n` corrected it (so: `file:^path/to/file.ext$ \n patterntype:regexp` instead)